# Отправка формы после после подтверждения

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $(document).ready( function(){ 
        $("form").submit(function() { 
            confirmation("Вы действительно хотите удалить аккаунт?", "Да", "Отмена", function (result) {
                 if(result == true) $("form").submit(); //return true не работает
            });
            return false;
        }) 
    });
```

Имеется форма, на ней кнопка удалить аккаунт, по нажатию на кнопку выскакивает подтверждение удаления, и далее форма должна отправляться, но нет.. `confirmation` callback функция, которая возвращает да или нет, как поменять код не правя функцию confirmation?
**UPD:**

```
function confirmation(message, ok, cancel, callback) {

    if (!$('#confirmation').length) {
        var string = 
        'html';
        $('<div/>').attr('id', 'confirmation').css("display", "none").html(string).appendTo('body');
    }

    var result;
    $.fancybox($('#confirmation'), {
        modal : true,
        autoSize: true,
        beforeShow: function() {
            $("#confirmation-message").text(message);

            $("#confirmation-btn-ok").unbind("click").bind("click", function() {
                result = true; 
                $.fancybox.close();
                return false;
            })
            $("#confirmation-btn-cancel").unbind("click").bind("click", function() {
                result = false; 
                $.fancybox.close();
                return false;
            })
        },
        afterClose: function() {
            callback.call(this, result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: что это за функция _confirmation_?

Comment: функция через fanxybox выводит поверх окна форму вопроса и ответы да, нет, обрабатывает нажатие и возвращает результат

Comment: очевидно - не возвращает :-) - стоит добавить реализацию этой функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае идет постоянная рекурсия, так как если подтвердили отправку вызывается тот же обработчик, который опять вызывает `confirmation` функцию.

Для решения, можно вызывать запускать обработчик с помощью [функции `trigger`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) и передавать дополнительный параметр, который обрабатывать, например так:

```
$(document).ready( function(){ 
    $("form").submit(function(e, approved) { 
        if(approved) return true;
        confirmation("Вы действительно хотите удалить аккаунт?", "Да", "Отмена", function (result) {
             if(result == true) $("form").trigger('submit',true); 
        });
        return false;
    }) 
});
```